$C^{2+\alpha}$ proprieties
Let $0<\alpha<1$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a $C^{2+\alpha}$ bounded domain.
Hi! I am reading the paper: How to appoximate the heat equation with Neumann Boundary Condition by nonLocal Diffusion Problem (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00205-007-0062-8.pdf [page 9 of pdf])
and I am a quite a bit longer in this statement and I really don’t know why this is happen. Consider $\bar{x}\in \partial{\Omega}$ a ortogonal projection of $x$ such that $x=\bar{x}-s\eta(\bar{x})$, with $0<s<\epsilon$, then we can choose $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ so that there exists $k>0$ and constants $f_i(\bar{x})$ such that
$B(\bar{x},2\epsilon)\cap\{y\in \mathbb{R}^n; y_N-\bigg(x_N+\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}f(\bar{x})(y_i-x_i)^2)\bigg)>\kappa e^{2+\alpha}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^N-\Omega$
$B(\bar{x},2\epsilon)\cap\{y\in \mathbb{R}^n; y_N-\bigg(x_N+\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}f(\bar{x})(y_i-x
_i)^2)\bigg)<-\kappa e^{2+\alpha}\}\subset \Omega$
Why there is this square power in $y_i-x_i$? Does it became by the fact that $\Omega$ has “soft” boundary, ie, no cusp? I couldn’t see this even in lower dimension. Can someone give me a type?
